# How to test In app purchase. Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I want to test  In app purchase in my application and I have few questions about that.

1. How long should I wait (few hours, fewa days)until I get Google Play link into my application for my testers? 
   ( I mean this link in: Google Play Developers console -> All application -> APK -> Bta Testing -> Manage list of testers )
2. If I change my APK 'Upload new APK to Beta' this waiting process for link will start over again or can I use the same link for test?
3. Am I need to publish my app first before I get this link ? I mean my app is beta so it will be available only for my testers but am I need to publish it in 'Game Services' tab.
4. I uploaded my app yesterday into my phone via USB cable. When I try to test 'In app purchase' I got information:
   'Conection Responce: 0 Setup succesful ( responce: 0:OK). '
   Then typical window of Google Play opened but I got this information:
   'Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account.'
   But I was using google account in my phone.
   Do you think I did something wrong  in my  code of application or because I tried test it in application that I uloaded via USB cable instead install it from Google Play site?

Ps. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S6

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where you need to publish something for an app that uses Google Play Games Services to make it available to beta testers.

1. Under the "All Applications" section (Android icon in the left frame), select your app, then go to the "APK" subsection to publish it for beta testing.
2. Under the "Game Services" section (game controller icon in the left frame), select your app, then select "Publishing" to make Google Play Games Services available to the users of your app.

Both of these steps will require you to fill in additional information in other sections as prerequisites for publishing.

After publishing in either of these sections it will take a few hours for publishing to take effect. When you publish an app for the first time you will get the link to your published app only once the publishing step has completed. The link is available from the "APK" subsection that I referenced above. The link will remain unchanged when you re-publish the app. Your testers will receive the latest available published version of your app when they follow the link. Re-publishing can take a few hours as well, so your testers would see the old version until that's done.

A user of the app needs to sign into Google Play Games Services as an additional step even when they are already signed into their Google account on the phone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. That's makes sense. My application had 'Draft' status ( "All Applications" section). I published it now I have 'PENDING PUBLICATION' status.   So if it will have 'published' status I'll get that link for testers.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer addressed your questions, please consider marking it as accepted.